# Are these surfaces closed?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I know if these two surfaces $$x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} + z^2 = 1\quad \text{and}\quad x^6 + y^6 + z^6 = 1$$ are closed without using a computer program ?

Comment: What do you mean by closed? Topologically closed (ie including their limit points)?

Comment: I just want to know if these surfaces delimit a region in space.

Comment: They have no point outside the cube $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$, hence they are bounded.

Answer (score 2):

The las one is the inverse image of the unit sphere $S^2$ under the homeomorphism from $\mathbf R^3$ onto itself given by
$$
(x,y,z)\mapsto (x^3,y^3,z^3).
$$
And similarly for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by closed you mean compact without boundary, in which case for the second it is enough to check if it is bounded since it is the level set of a regular value of a $C^\infty$ function. In fact it is bounded since $x^6\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ implies that $x,y,z\leq 1$

For the first one you need to specify what $x^{2/3}$ means. What is the domain?